# mDNS in AngularJS applications?

Tags: angularjs, http, dns, ionic-framework, mdns

Is it possible to use mDNS lookups in AngularJS applications?

More specifically I'm making an app through the Ionic framework (which run upon AngularJS). And I want it to be able to connect to an embedded device on the network.

For example:

```
 $http.get("mydevice.local", .....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used node mDNS on my Linux machine. But it has parts written in c++.

https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns

Chrome has had an mDNS API since Chrome 31.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mdns

Comment: Looks like it creates a mDNS server? can it also just translate an URL (mydevice.local for example) to an IP address?.. ie. serve as mDNS client? :)

Comment: I have used it both as a server and as a client of mDNS.

Comment: Now that I think of it, node_mdns has parts written on c++. There is the Chrome mDNS API for extensions.